# Firebase UI Recyclerview is not updating when new items are inserted in the Firestore collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want my recyclerview to get updated whenever the collection changes so according to the Firebase-ui docs I don't need to do much because it's handled automatically if I just add adapter.listening to the onstart and onpause activity methods

I have setup adapter.listening in onstart method but when new items are added to the collection the UI doesn't loads it until I pause the activity and onstart is called
Activity code :

```
package net.raj.mushimushi.ui.comments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query
import net.raj.mushimushi.databinding.ActivityCommentSectBinding
import net.raj.mushimushi.models.Comments

class CommentSectActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding :ActivityCommentSectBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: CommentAdapter
    private val viewModel : CommentViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var postId : String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCommentSectBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        postId = CommentSectActivityArgs.fromBundle(intent?.extras!!).postId


        binding.postCommentButton.setOnClickListener{
            val text = binding.commentInput.text.toString()
            viewModel.addComment(text, postId)
        }

        setUpRecyclerView()

        setContentView(binding.root)

    }



    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        val query = viewModel.commentCollection.whereEqualTo(
            "postId",
            postId
        ).orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        val recyclerViewOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comments>().setQuery(
            query,
            Comments::class.java
        ).build()
        adapter = CommentAdapter(recyclerViewOptions)

        binding.recyclerView2.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerView2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter.stopListening()
    }
}
```

Here is my implementation of recyclerview adapter provided by Firebase UI

```
package net.raj.mushimushi.ui.comments

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import net.raj.mushimushi.R
import net.raj.mushimushi.models.Comments

class CommentAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Comments>) : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Comments,CommentAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        options
) {

    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val commentBox : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentBox)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_comment, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, model: Comments) {
        holder.commentBox.text = model.text
    }


}
```

Comment: If you add `Log.d("TAG", model.text)` inside `onBindViewHolder` is something printed out in the logcat? Please edit your question and add the content of your `Comments` and your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem :
Actually I should I have created a composite index in the firestore because I have been using compound queries with a range of clause so I need to setup indexes for that in the firestore

doc link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing